# Jenkins maven build fails on windows slave, but works via command line

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

I did not see an answer that solved my issue, so here it is.  I have a simple maven project used to execute testNG automated tests.  When I build the package via command line with `mvn clean install` in the project's root directory, everything builds fine and the tests run.

However, when I run this build from jenkins, the build fails with `Error: Could not find or load main class jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main`.  It seems as though Jenkins is not able read the jars in the slave's base folder.  Below are the details:

Jenkins log:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on AUTOMATION-DEV (test) in workspace workspace/PreSale API
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git://github.ove.local/QA/ODS.git
Checking out Revision ad9aedb4b1bee8804d95c663c01bf1d696d711a6 (origin/ods_presales_api)
Parsing POMs
Copied maven32-agent.jar
Copied maven32-interceptor.jar
Copied maven3-interceptor-commons.jar
[ODSPreSalesApi] $ java -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -cp maven32-agent.jar;C:\apache-maven-3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\apache-maven-3.3.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main C:\apache-maven-3.3.3 

C:\jenkins\launcher\slave.jar maven32-interceptor.jar maven3-interceptor-commons.jar 57700
Error: Could not find or load main class jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
testng-results.xml was last modified before this build started. Ignoring it.
Saving reports...
Found matching files but did not find any TestNG results.
Finished: FAILURE
```

PATH(related to issue):

```
%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\jenkins\launcher;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

M2_HOME:

```
C:\apache-maven-3.3.3
```

M2:

```
C:\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
```

I'm new to maven configurations in Jenkins, so I am assuming I am missing something simple.

PS - I have created special Jenkins configurations for the windows slave pointing maven to the `C:\apache-maven-3.3.3` and java home directory.  These are configured on the build job.